# Android: FragmentTabHost null Fragments

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, android-tabs, fragment-tab-host

I have a Fragment which contains a FragmentTabHost. I set it up here:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings_organization, container, false);
        Log.v(TabHome.TAG, "SettingsOrganization onCreateView()");
        setUpActionBar();

        TextView headerView =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.orgNameHeader);
        headerView.setText(organization.name);

     //   showSpinner(true);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        mTabHost.setup(activity, this.getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
        mTabHost.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("text")
                        .setIndicator(getString(R.string.settings_text_select), activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home)),
                SettingsOrganizationTabFragment_.class, null
        );


        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("voice")
                        .setIndicator(getString(R.string.settings_voice_select), activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home)),
                SettingsOrganizationTabFragment_.class, null
        );

        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("app")
                        .setIndicator(getString(R.string.settings_app_select), activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home)),
                SettingsOrganizationTabFragment_.class, null
        );


        restClient = new RestClient_();
        SettingsOrganizationErrorHandler errorHandler = new SettingsOrganizationErrorHandler();
        restClient.setRestErrorHandler(errorHandler);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = restClient.getRestTemplate();
        ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = RestClientHelper.clientHttpRequestFactory();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
        RestClientHelper.prepareRestClient(restClient);
        restClient.setHeader("Auth-Token",TabHome.authToken);

        GetSettingsTask task = new GetSettingsTask();
        task.execute();


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("text"));
        }

        return v;
    }
```

You can also see here that I start a background task to fetch some data. When this is completed, I need to update all three tabs. The problem is that only the first tab exists; the others are null.

I have also tried to update the other tabs in onTabChanged(), but in this case frag is null when it is not the first tab:

```
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        Log.v(TabHome.TAG,"Tab ID:"+ tabId);
        SettingsOrganizationTabFragment frag = (SettingsOrganizationTabFragment)thisFrag.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tabId);
        if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("text")){
            frag.notificationType=SettingsOrganizationTabFragment.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_TEXT;
            frag.settings =settings;
            frag.updateView();
        }

        if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("voice")){
            frag.notificationType=SettingsOrganizationTabFragment.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_VOICE;
            frag.settings =settings;
            frag.updateView();
        }

        if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("app")){
            frag.notificationType=SettingsOrganizationTabFragment.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_APP;
            frag.settings =settings;
            frag.updateView();
        }
    }
});
```

(thisFrag refers to the fragment containing the fragmentTabHost)

How can I update the other tabs even if they have not yet been shown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to create the tabs if they're still null, or use model from the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern. I suggest the second option. When you actually create the tab you will then take the information you need for your tab from the model.

```
public class SecondTab {
private Model model;
private String infoS;
private int infoI;
private boolean infoB;

    public SecondTab(Model model) {
        this.model = model;
        infoS = model.getInfoS();
        infoI = model.getInfoI();
        infoB = model.getInfoB
    }

    public void editInfoS(String s){
        model.setInfoS(s);
    }
}
```

You would then pass then add the updated info to your model when your tab should be updated. When you actually create the tab you just pass the model to it.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how I would create the tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using my tab fragment's onResume() method, which is called each time the tab is selected. I reach up and grab the parent fragment (which has the fetched data I need), and then update the tab accordingly if the data is present.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    Log.v(TabHome.TAG, "SettingsOrganizationTab - onResume");
    super.onResume();
    TabHome.activeFragment = this;
    activity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

    parent = (SettingsOrganizationFragment)this.getParentFragment();
    Log.v(TabHome.TAG,"Selected Tab: "+parent.mTabHost.getCurrentTab());
    notificationType = parent.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    if (parent.settings!=null){

        updateView();
    }


}
```